# how to get device precise location using dialogflow fulfillment

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I need to get permission from user in order to get device precise/course location using dialogflow-fulfillment i'm using below code but getting error as

> ReferenceError: Permission is not defined

```
 const conv = agent.conv(); 
            const options = { context: 'To locate you', permissions: ['NAME', 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION']}; 
            conv.ask(new Permission(options)); 
            agent.add(conv);
```

i dont get any sample/template code how to use permission from dialogflow or how to construct payload for location access especially using dialogflow-
fulfillment(WebhookClient({request:req,response:res})) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by taking Permission from actions on google like below

```
const {Permission} = require('actions-on-google');
const conv = agent.conv(); 
    conv.ask(new Permission({
    context: 'To locate you',
    permissions: 'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION',
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The new way of doing things is "documented" here:

https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/lib-v1-migration

in the paragraph titled

**Intent handler helpers and arguments**

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that Permission is defined in the object returned when you require('actions-on-google');

Comment: i'm using dialogflow-fulfillment creating instance agent in that i am taking let conv=agent.conv() but still getting same error

Comment: Thanks for guidance finally solved it. William DePalo